# MYSQL pivot table create

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I've tried various tutorials and examples how to make a dynamic pivot table, and I cant make it work. Every time I am getting some sql error.

Can someone help me how to make dynamic pivot table. I am new, and I guess I will make a filter search by attributes easy when I make pivot table first. Here are my tables:

Table 1 name: table_items

```
------------------------------
| item_id |   title    | ... |
------------------------------
|    1    |  item 1    | ... |
------------------------------
|    2    |  item 2    | ... |
------------------------------
```

Table 2 name: table_item_options

```
-----------------------------
| option_id |   option_name |
-----------------------------
|    1      |     Color     |
-----------------------------
|    2      |     Size      |
-----------------------------
```

Table 3 name: table_attributes

```
--------------------------------------------------
| attribute_id |   option_id    | attribute_name |
--------------------------------------------------
|      1       |       1        |      Blue      |
--------------------------------------------------
|      2       |       1        |      Red       |
--------------------------------------------------
|      3       |       2        |      XL        |
--------------------------------------------------
|      4       |       1        |      Green     |
--------------------------------------------------
|      5       |       2        |      L         |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Table 4 name: table_item_attributes

```
------------------------------------------------------
| assigned_id |  item_id  | option_id | attribute_id |
------------------------------------------------------
|      1      |     1     |     1     |      1       |
------------------------------------------------------
|      1      |     1     |     1     |      2       |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help is much appreciated

What I want is to make a product filter for items by its attributes. As I understood it is best possible to make a pivot table, and to avoid duplicate results bu joining tables.

All first columns are primary keys, and with autoincrement.

EDIT:
At this point, using inner join , I create one big table, and in Select clause I put " WHERE attribute_id = '2' ". (Which means Select all Red) , but like this I can use only one filter.

So I have a problem that I cant use more than one filter from attribute_id column, and I want to filter by more attributes (other color, other size, city,  etc..)

So how can I do this using pivot table ? My intention is to dinamicly create columns which would be option.name from (table_item_options) and to populate it with attribute_id or attribute_name, so I can use more filters

for example:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| item_id |  ...  | color    | size | City  | etc.. |
------------------------------------------------------
|      1  |  ... | 1(or Red) | L    | A     | ...   |
------------------------------------------------------
|      1  |  ... | 2(or Blue)| XL   | B      | ...  |
------------------------------------------------------
```

In table like this, If I Select * .. where color = red , I will be able to filter this table by another column, eg:  Where city = a

I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: What's your SQL error? `table_item_attributes` is a pivot table for items and attributes, you don't need the `option_id` field in it (you've got another pivot table for that). Not sure what `assigned_id` is either, but if it's supposed to be a primary key, then you'll need to set it to auto increment and be a primary key otherwise duplicating that ID will cause SQL errors.

Comment: whats your desired outcome?? what do you want to happen... making a product filter doesn't mean much to us.. show us some data.. what you want to do.. what manipulations you want.

Comment: It's best to handle issues of data display in your application-level code / presentation layer. While dynamic pivot tables are possible in MySQL, they are (IMO) quite tedious.